# Rust Rc<RefCell>::borrow_mut returns &mut Rc<RefCell<T>> instead of RefMut<T>

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

so I'm relatively new in Rust and I was trying to get something similair to a std::shared_ptr in C++. I decided to go with the Rc<RefCell> pattern.

I'm trying to get and modify the value of `Rc<RefCell<i32>>` but `borrow_mut()` keeps returning `&mut Rc<RefCell<i32>>` instead of `MutRef<i32>`

I'm working on 2 projects currently. In the first project `test_mut` is of type `RefMut<i32>`.

```
let mut test: Rc<RefCell<i32>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(5));
let test_mut = test.borrow_mut();
```

But in my other project `test_mut` is of type `&mut Rc<RefCell<i32>>`.

WHYYY??

When I don't let the compiler deduct the type and replace the code with:

```
let mut test: Rc<RefCell<i32>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(5));
let test_mut: RefMut<i32> = test.borrow_mut();
```

I get the following error:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `RefMut<'_, i32>`
found mutable reference `&mut Rc<RefCell<i32>>`
```

If anyone has any idea how I can prevent this, you would be my hero :)

Comment: Did you let your IDE auto complete the funtion? I have an issue where my IDE will import [`std::borrow::BorrowMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.BorrowMut.html#tymethod.borrow_mut) instead of the one implemented by the `RefCell`. Just delete the import and it should work correctly.

Comment: It works on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=422bbfedcb3b6205b8457c7ec7581f4d)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locke's comment is right.

Because of the [method resolution rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html), if you have `use std::borrow::BorrowMut;`, `BorrowMut::borrow_mut` will get called instead of `RefCell::borrow_mut`. Basically, trait methods on the current type (`&mut RefCell`) are checked before methods on the deref type (`&Rc`).

You can either remove the import, or call it as an associated function:

```rs
let test_mut = RefCell::borrow_mut(&test);
```

This isn't necessary here, but the equivalent code without automatic deref would be:

```rs
use std::ops::Deref;
let test_mut = RefCell::borrow_mut(Deref::deref(&test))
```